# How to check all the elements in a list that has a specific requirement?

Tags: python, list

I'm doing a homework about a heart game with different version. It says that if we are given a list **mycards** that contains all the cards that player currently hold in their hands. And **play** is a single card that representing a potential card.And if **all** their cards contain either HEART(`H`) or QUEEN OF SPADES(`QS`) it is going to return True.

*For example*

```
>>> mycards= ['0H','8H','7H','6H','AH','QS']
>>> play = ['QS']
```

It will return True

this is what I have tried

```
if play[1] == 'H':
    return True
if play == 'QS':
    return True
else:
    return False
```

But I think my codes just check one QS and one H in the list. How to make the codes that contain `all` either QS or H?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your description maps directly to the solution:

Edited for clarity:

```
mycards= ['0H','8H','7H','6H','AH','QS'] 
all((x == 'QS' or 'H' in x) for x in mycards)
#  True
```

Comment: "Your description maps directly to the solution" +1

Comment: I would put the more general case first, so as to use the optimization given by the `or` operator, which does not evaluate remaining terms as soon as one term yields True.

Comment: Note that the question only tests the explicit `x[1] == 'H'`, not the less restrictive and slower `'H' in x`.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> mycards= ['0H','8H','7H','6H','AH','QS']
>>> all(x[-1] == 'H' or x == 'QS' for x in mycards)
True
```

Comment: Not sure how this is different than what Thomas posted.

Comment: I don't think `x[-1] == 'H'` is needed - as far as I know (and coffee is on its way), only one suit in a deck of cards starts with `H`.

Comment: +1, because the original question contains the equivalent `x[1]`. This is also faster than `'H' in x`.

Answer (score 2):

Since its your 'Homework' I'm not going to provide you with ready-made code. :)

Iterate over the list using a loop:

for eg.:

```
for el in mycards:
```

at each iteration you have to check either any of the two conditions are true or not.

```
if el == 'QS' or el[1] == 'H':
```

if card is either Queen of Spade or a Heart above condition will be true. Hope you get it till now. And if the condition is not true, simply return False.

If all the elements in your lists are checked by the loop and yet no False returned, hence the all cards are either Queen of Spade or a Heart. So return True after the loop ends.

Try on your own for a while, if still not getting I'll post the code at your request (but you'll have to show me what you tried :p)

Edit:
Since you've tried it, I'm posting code too.

```
def HorQS(mycards):
    for i in mycards:
        if i != 'QS':
            if i[1] != 'H':
                return False
    return True

print HorQS(['0H','8H','7H','6H','AH','QS'])  # True
print HorQS(['0H','8H','7H','6H','AH','HS'])  # False
print HorQS(['0H','8H','7K','6H','AH','HS'])  # False
```

Comment: Python has `all()` so that people do not have to reinvent the wheel like here, and so that the meaning of their code is much more obvious. I would not encourage anybody to use such a complicated solution (which is only needed in a language like C).

Comment: I was aiming more at explaining asker how his code should work. Thinking & framing the algorithm in asker's mind was my primary motive. And since it was very easy question, & yet he asked clearly suggests asker's weakness in converting his requirements to codes. I agree with all(), but yet it should be the later of the explanation, or else students will simply believe that "Oh yea, this function does my work, who cares what's happening inside". I just don't want newbies to think that way.

Comment: @RaviOjha: OK, -1 removed. Side note: I *do* want new Python programmers to use `all()` instead of going through a possible implementation of it in Python. This is for the same reason that I would not suggest that a student also learns assembly language so that they understand how Python implements its so convenient features. :) Everybody understand what "all cards are either hearts or maybe queen of spades" means, and Python just allows one to express this. They can concentrate on other tasks than implementing this, like nice projects that *leverage* the power of Python, not *lower* it. :)

Comment: I think it's good that you don't use `all` to start off with.  I mean, it's also good to know that it exists, but you should know what it's doing.

Comment: @EOL sure we should shift to 'all()' or respective inbuilt library functions soon after we learn how its working(+1). And as Tyr commented we should not use such functions right away(+1 for that too).

Comment: @Tyr: Yeah, it is very important to know what `all()`. My point is that you don't have to program it in order to understand it: `if all(…)` almost reads like English! When I teach Python, I never need to go "down" to lower levels of programming: instead, students love learning the power offered by Python and its high-level functions, and they can spend more time building more interesting projects (than writing C-like code that they should never use again).

Comment: But if you ever needed `all_but_one()` or something like that it'd be better if you had a mental model of how `all()` worked internally.